# IPC Message/Data from C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, pipe, ipc, shared-memory

I have a message variable in my Java code. I want to be able to input data (let's say a string for now) from another message variable in C++ code into the variable I have in the Java code. From my research it seems I can do this using IPC Shared Memory, and/or piping. It isn't exactly clear how I can get started with this concept though. Below is my java code with the message variable.

Recv File

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.*; 
import java.io.IOException;

public class Recv 
{
    public static String recv(String ip, String Q) throws Exception 
{

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost(ip);
    factory.setUsername("test");
    factory.setPassword("test");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");
    MyConsumer consumer=new MyConsumer(channel);
    channel.basicConsume(Q,true,consumer);

    return consumer.getStoredMessage();
}

public static class MyConsumer extends DefaultConsumer 
{
    public String storedMessage;

    public MyConsumer(Channel channel) 
    {
        super(channel);
    }

    public String getStoredMessage() 
    {
        return storedMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
        throws IOException 
    {
        String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
        storedMessage = message; // store message here
    }
}
}
```

Send file

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;   
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;

public class Send {

public static void send(String ip, String Q) throws Exception {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

    //set connection info
    factory.setHost(ip);
    factory.setUsername("test");
    factory.setPassword("test");

    //create connection
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();

    //create channel
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    //publish message
    int a = 1; 
    while (a!=0)
    {
        channel.queueDeclare(Q, false, false, false, null);
        for(int i=1; i<=2; i++)
        {
            String message = "Pizza #"+i;
            channel.basicPublish("", Q, null, message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'" + Q);
        }

        a--;
    }

    //SHUT IT ALL DOWN!
    channel.close();
    connection.close();
}
}
```

Comment: First thing to do is decide on which IPC you want to use.  This is a question unto itself, but ask it with your research done ahead of time.